# How do I create a custom UITableViewCell with nib in Xcode 4?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4, uitableview

In Xcode 3, I could elect to make a nib when creating a table view cell subclass.  In Xcode 4, it only makes the h / m files.

How do I make the subclass with a xib file?

Edit: see screen shots below:

[image: New File]

[image]

**EDIT:**
Additionally, is there any way to create the UITableViewCell nib automatically, along with the h and m files, all pre-wired and ready to edit?

Comment: Where?  When I select: File, New File, Cocoa Touch, Objective-C Class, Next, (type class name), select UITableViewCell from drop down list, Next...it then goes to the create dialog.  Nowhere is an option to check with xib for user interface.

Comment: Not getting question proprly..can you please explain your question inmore simpler way?So maybe I can help.

Comment: Still don't see where or how to create the nib file in XCode 4...

Comment: Here is a similar question: [How to create a UINavigationItem.TitleView based upon a nib file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286507/how-to-create-a-uinavigationitem-titleview-based-upon-a-nib-file).

Comment: Create xib(nib) file: `File`->`New`->`New File`->`User Interface`->`View`.

Comment: This [link](http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/) may bel helpful to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [blog post](http://idevnotes.wordpress.com/2011/09/14/custom-uitableview-in-xcode4-xib/) describes, how to add it manually.

in iOS4+, the line

```
NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@”CustomCell” owner:self options:nil];
```

can be replaced by a more efficient nib handling via `UINib`.
see this [blog post](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/2/28/speeding-up-table-view-cell-loading-with-uinib.html) how to do it, and how to stay backwards compatible.

Comment: Great link, but is there a way to not do it manually?  Or is that the only way?

Comment: It is the only way I ever needed. and a quite elegant one compared to others, that uses xibs without a proper file owner.

Comment: Are all the default connections are wired already, such as backgroundView and contentView, or do I need to manually connect them?  What about textLabel?

Comment: Actually I am not sure, if this connection gets established, as you are not passing in a certain cellStyle. Try it out!

Comment: Doing it the way its shown sets it up as a UITableViewCell, so it still keeps its properties.  The first link does have an error though, it should be: @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *customCell;

Answer (score 1):

As I understood you already have .h/.m files and you are missing the view (nib).

1. Please select new file, select "User Interface" category and empty
   in sub category.
2. Once your nib is created, drag and drop the
   UITableViewCell on the screen.
3. Set the class as First Responder.

Comment: Close, but step three is incorrect (see @vikingosegundo link).  If I don't have the h / m files, can I make the nib, h and m files all at once somehow (All pre-wired)?