# How add two images side by side in a UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimage

How add two images side by side in a UITableViewCell?
The style of UITableViewCell is UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle.

Comment: Hmm what have you tried ? Are you familiar with making custom table view cells ?

Comment: I'm beginner, I'm not familiar with making custom table view cell

Comment: customize your tableview cell by subclassing `UITableViewCell` & overriding method `layoutSubviews`. U can refer to steps given in the UIView class reference under section Subclassing notes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you start doing anything unusual in a UITableViewCell, it's time to create your own custom subclass of UITableView cell. Trying to muck around with the defaults iOS gives you will only lead to pain and misery.

There are many tutorials and examples out there on the net and it's quite simple to do, e.g.

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html

Make sure you pay attention to how everything is wired up in Interface Builder. With XCode 4 you'll also have to create the NIB/XIB on your own in a separate step - see a previous stack overflow response to this here:

[How do I create a custom UITableViewCell with nib in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291518/how-do-i-create-a-custom-uitableviewcell-with-nib-in-xcode-4)